# How to use ARM template condition to exclude resource property

Tags: if-statement, templates, conditional-statements, azure-resource-manager

I am authoring a Azure template spec for creating a disk and would like the template spec to create the disk with or without an Availability Zone. The problem I have is when the client selects 'None' for the Availability Zone, the "zones" member cannot be present (as far as I can tell because setting it to any value such as empty string, etc. other than an actual zone number results in an error).

I tried two resources in the "resources": [] array with appropriate conditions, but this gave me an error regarding members being duplicated.

Does anyone know how I can have one template spec that conditionally drops the             ***"zones": [
"[parameters('zone')]"
]***

from the "resources": [] array when the client selects Availability Zone of 'None' and includes it when they select an zone?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

`"zones": "[if(equals(length(parameters('zone')), 0), json('null'), parameters('zone'))]"`

See: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.network/azurefirewall-create-with-zones/azuredeploy.json#L129 for a sample.

Comment: I tried:

"zones": ["[if(equals(parameters('zone'), 'None'), json('null'), parameters('zone'))]"],

I get: {"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"InvalidAvailabilityZone","message":"The zone(s) '' for resource 'Microsoft.Compute/disks/newdisk' is not supported. The supported for location 'eastus' are '1,2,3'"}]}

It seems disk without zone must exclude "zones":.

Comment: Figured it out. This works:

"zones": "[if(equals(parameters('availabilityZone'), 'None'), json('null'), array(parameters('availabilityZone')))]",